# How to set onclick actions on Google maps objects?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, onclick

I've created a map with an API key. Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        let map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), {
                center: {
                    lat: 51.513329,
                    lng: -0.088950
                },
                zoom: 14
            });



        }

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:myCenter,
    url: '/',
    animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
marker.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {alert('Hi');});

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to set onclick actions for objects - any markers or map objects.
For ex, when I click on a city, I want to launch a script and get data for current coords, map names.

This code should launch alert on click, also get current data from labels (boxes).
This doesn't work in Edge, although the code is from a demo

How to set onclick functions for markers or map with getting data from clicked objects?

I've tried Google docs

Here are listeners for onclick actions

They should work.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {alert('Hi');});
```

But the map doesn't show Hi alerts or click functions.

Seems that google is not defined here